# Cloud SQL marginally slower than localhost server

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, laravel-5.5, google-cloud-sql, php-7.2

I have trouble understanding why Cloud SQL is marginally slower than my localhost MySQL server.

I can accept that a little variation can occur from configuration to configuration but...

In localhost it only takes 240 milliseconds to fulfill a query that just returns all records from a table with its relationships (there's only 90 records) while in Cloud SQL it takes almost **30 seconds**. And It's just like 28kb of data.

I am using PHP with Laravel 5.5. According to all the GCP docs I have all the configuration needed.

I don't think it is a quota problem.

Using second gen Cloud SQL and connecting from App Engine flex environment with auto-scale.

I did improve the server specs of the Cloud SQL instance to 1.7 GB RAM. I don't think it is a server performance related issue...

Thanks.

---

#### Edit

This is confusing.

I am debugging the raw SQL strings being executed and when I use DD to debug I am preventing the JSON response and it takes just 1 second. A lot better by some reason I can't understand.

**This is the one ending faster**

```
DB::enableQueryLog();

Contact::with([
    'rooms',
    'bathrooms',
    'parkingLots',
    'generalInterests',
    'locationInterests',
    'strongInterests',
    'phonePrefix',
    'source',
    'contactType'
])->get();

dd(DB::getQueryLog());

return new JsonResponse([
    'query' => 'all',
    'results' => Contact::with([
        'rooms',
        'bathrooms',
        'parkingLots',
        'generalInterests',
        'locationInterests',
        'strongInterests',
        'phonePrefix',
        'source',
        'contactType'
    ])->get()
], 200);
```

**And this is the one that just takes the same loooong time**

```
DB::enableQueryLog();

Contact::with([
    'rooms',
    'bathrooms',
    'parkingLots',
    'generalInterests',
    'locationInterests',
    'strongInterests',
    'phonePrefix',
    'source',
    'contactType'
])->get();

Log::debug(print_r(DB::getQueryLog(), true));

return new JsonResponse([
    'query' => 'all',
    'results' => Contact::with([
        'rooms',
        'bathrooms',
        'parkingLots',
        'generalInterests',
        'locationInterests',
        'strongInterests',
        'phonePrefix',
        'source',
        'contactType'
    ])->get()
], 200);
```

As you can see, the only difference is the return being reached or not.

---

#### Edit 2

### Problem found

Turns out that when returning the JSON response, the Eloquent model processes the appenders of the model which make some requests to another API REST and it does that for each model in the result set.

In localhost, that same operation just returns null before making the request. So, there's my problem.

Nothing to do with MySQL, GCP, Laravel, or PHP. Just my own dumbness.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this absurd question. My most sincere apologies.

Comment: Asier Paz Martínez may I ask you to post the solution as an answer?

Comment: There's no solution involving any of the technologies mentioned above. The thing is that in localhost, the appender function didn't execute the API request and in production it did. So there's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the throughput of your Internet connection? That is the main difference between your 2 environments. Other ways to determine the cause include: running a query straight from SQL, checking your logs (especially the SQL DB log), trying the same query from another location.

In my experience, running a query straight from SQL may give you the best help. Just a basic `SELECT * from my_table;` and see how long that takes. And I found this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues) on the Google site, it might help you with investigation and tuning tips. It mentions AppEngine limits, but with that amount of data, I don't think you are running into any of those.

Comment: Firs of all thank you for taking the time to answer. If I do the queries directly with mysql client they take the expected time. I also saw that document a few times and it's of no help at all.

Comment: Wow. Umm, in that case I don't think it's the database itself. I'm not an expert with AppEngine, but those signs point to an issue with one of the components in your app and how it relates to AppEngine.